# Display meta-field mp3 and add to lightbox container on portfolio page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

### What I basically have now:

I have a portfolio gallery masonry grid (using JIG plugin) that queries my custom post_type.
For each post, clicking on the thumbnail will trigger a lightbox showing the photo.
JIG allows you to use many different lightbox versions (`PrettyPhoto, JP Carousel, ColorBox , PhotoSwipe`), The lightbox's can be configured to display descriptions, captions, authors, dates & times, alt text, and a few more fields from within JIG itself.

## The desired goal:

1. In the lightbox, I want to display an audio player, and pulling its src from the current post shown **just as if it were** a title, alt text, or caption field.
2. I've setup the frontend add new post form for it to accept a mp3 url which saves the url to the mp3 in "my_meta_field"...
3. I use the shortcode which injects the url into the  markup. Defaults to the current post, but can be configured to accept $parent_post, or any other variable.

Methods I've tried using to call the field from shortcode and standard methods.
[`types field="my_meta_field"`] or `echo types_render_field( "my_meta_field", array("output" => "raw")`  or `get_post_meta()`

What's the most straightforward, and simple way to get the `<audio mp3="my_custom_field"> </audio>` code to pass through the lightbox's query and display it inside of the lightbox container?

Comment: http://audiosparksforart.ronnietrainham.com/artsparks/uploads/2014/07/Untitled-1024x564.png  Here is a screenshot of the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes were to include the additional info for carusel (it works separately), remove the caption from the link of the thumbnail so you can interact with the player and not open the carousel immediately (and to allow HTML in it).

```
justified-image-grid.php v2.0.4

line 1304

                wp_enqueue_script('justified-image-grid', plugins_url('js/justified-image-grid-min.js', __FILE__), 'jquery', self::PLUGIN_VERSION, true);

became

                wp_enqueue_script('justified-image-grid', plugins_url('js/justified-image-grid.js', __FILE__), 'jquery', self::PLUGIN_VERSION, true);

(loading unminified JS)

after line 8117 New code is inserted:


                            if($recents_post_type == 'project'){
                                $audio_url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pf_podsnack', true );
                                if(!empty($audio_url)){
                                    if (strpos($audio_url, 'iframe') === false){
                                        $d['description'] .= '<audio controls="controls" preload="auto">
                                                            <source src="'.$audio_url.'" type="audio/mpeg">
                                                            </audio>';
                                        }else{
                                            $d['description'] .= $audio_url;
                                        }

                                }

                            }

In future versions the line numbering will change but you'll find this area 2 lines before the line:

                            switch ($recents_link_to) {

Line 8143 

                                        $data['carousel_data'] = $this->jig_add_carousel_data(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), $link_title_field, $img_alt_field);


bacame

                                        $data['carousel_data'] = $this->jig_add_carousel_data(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), $d['title'], $d['description'], true);


Line 12136 new code inserted:

                            .justified-image-grid audio{
                                display: block;
                                width: 100%;
                            }
                            .jp-carousel-titleanddesc-desc audio,
                            .jp-carousel-titleanddesc-desc iframe{
                                display: block;
                            }
                            .justified-image-grid iframe{
                                display: block;
                                margin: 0 auto;
                            }


CSS styling of the audio and iframes.

12251

                wp_enqueue_script('justified-image-grid', plugins_url('js/justified-image-grid-min.js', __FILE__), 'jquery', self::PLUGIN_VERSION, true);


became 
                wp_enqueue_script('justified-image-grid', plugins_url('js/justified-image-grid.js', __FILE__), 'jquery', self::PLUGIN_VERSION, true);


(loading unminified JS)

line 14856

        function jig_add_carousel_data($attachment_id, $link_title_field, $img_alt_field){


became

        function jig_add_carousel_data($attachment_id, $link_title_field, $img_alt_field, $ready = false){


line 14873-14882

            // Get title
            $d['title'] =  esc_attr(stripslashes($attachment->post_title));
            $d['caption'] =  esc_attr(stripslashes($attachment->post_excerpt));
            $d['description'] =  esc_attr(stripslashes($attachment->post_content));
            $d['alternate'] =  esc_attr(stripslashes(get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true)));

            $attachment_title = $d[$img_alt_field] ? wptexturize($d[$img_alt_field]) : '';
            $attachment_desc = $d[$link_title_field] ? wpautop(wptexturize($d[$link_title_field])) : '';


became

            if($ready == false){
                // Get title
                $d['title'] =  esc_attr(stripslashes($attachment->post_title));
                $d['caption'] =  esc_attr(stripslashes($attachment->post_excerpt));
                $d['description'] =  esc_attr(stripslashes($attachment->post_content));
                $d['alternate'] =  esc_attr(stripslashes(get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true)));

                $attachment_title = $d[$img_alt_field] ? wptexturize($d[$img_alt_field]) : '';
                $attachment_desc = $d[$link_title_field] ? wpautop(wptexturize($d[$link_title_field])) : '';
            }else{
                $attachment_title = esc_attr($link_title_field);
                $attachment_desc = esc_attr($img_alt_field);
            }



----------

justified-image-grid.js


after 622 new code:

                s.element.on("click", ".jig-caption", function(event){
                    event.stopPropagation();
                });


1850-1867
                if(captionContent !== ''){
                    captionContent = '<div class="jig-caption-wrapper"><div class="jig-caption">'+captionContent+'</div></div>';

                    if(s.caption !== 'below'){
                        link.append(captionContent);
                    }else if(s.middleBorderWidth !== 0 && s.innerBorder == 'always' && s.middleBorder !== 'always'){
                        imageContainer.append($(captionContent).width(overflow.width()-2*parseFloat(s.innerBorderWidth)));
                    }else{
                        imageContainer.append($(captionContent).css({'width':overflow.css("width")}));
                    }
                }else if(s.caption == 'below'){
                    captionContent = '<div class="jig-caption-wrapper"></div>';
                    if(s.middleBorderWidth !== 0 && s.innerBorder == 'always' && s.middleBorder !== 'always'){
                        imageContainer.append($(captionContent).width(overflow.width()-2*parseFloat(s.innerBorderWidth)));
                    }else{
                        imageContainer.append($(captionContent).css({'width':overflow.css("width")}));
                    }
                }



became 

                if(captionContent !== ''){
                    captionContent = '<div class="jig-caption-wrapper"><div class="jig-caption">'+captionContent+'</div></div>';

                    if(s.caption !== 'below'){
                        overflow.append(captionContent);
                    }else if(s.middleBorderWidth !== 0 && s.innerBorder == 'always' && s.middleBorder !== 'always'){
                        overflow.append($(captionContent).html(captionContent).width(overflow.width()-2*parseFloat(s.innerBorderWidth)));
                    }else{
                        overflow.append($(captionContent).html(captionContent).css({'width':overflow.css("width")}));
                    }
                }else if(s.caption == 'below'){
                    captionContent = '<div class="jig-caption-wrapper"></div>';
                    if(s.middleBorderWidth !== 0 && s.innerBorder == 'always' && s.middleBorder !== 'always'){
                        overflow.append($(captionContent).html(captionContent).width(overflow.width()-2*parseFloat(s.innerBorderWidth)));
                    }else{
                        overflow.append($(captionContent).html(captionContent).css({'width':overflow.css("width")}));
                    }
                }


line 2246-2255

            input = htmlspecialchars_decode(input);

            if(s.caption == 'below'){
                return input; // Allowing links or anything when the caption is below the image (still need to decode)
            }
            allowed = (((allowed || "") + "").toLowerCase().match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || []).join(''); // making sure the allowed arg is a string containing only tags in lowercase (<a><b><c>)
            var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
                commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
            return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '').replace(tags, function ($0, $1) {
                return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
            });


became

            return $("<div/>").html(input).text();
            /*input = htmlspecialchars_decode(input);
            if(s.caption == 'below'){
                return input; // Allowing links or anything when the caption is below the image (still need to decode)
            }
            allowed = (((allowed || "") + "").toLowerCase().match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || []).join(''); // making sure the allowed arg is a string containing only tags in lowercase (<a><b><c>)
            var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
                commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
            return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '').replace(tags, function ($0, $1) {
                return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
            });*/
```